# Sample size calculation with continuous endpoint for two groups?

Tags: statistics

How can I calculate the sample size on this situation.

There are two groups, treatment and placebo. There is a difference of 6 points in the mean change of Treatment at `Day 30` from Baseline between Treatment and placebo.
We should have `1:1` randomization ratio. The SD is `12`, a power  is `85%`. It is two sided test with  alpha `5%`. We are expecting a drop out rate in `20%`.

How many subjects should be included in each group?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to find how many subjects should be included in each group to achieve 85% power and 20% drop out ?